# Where do I put the -p flag when running a "rails generate" in "pretend" mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The Rails help message says:

```
General options:
  -h, [--help]     # Print generator's options and usage
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output
```

I'm specifically interested in `-p` to see what files would be generated. However, the following commands don't work:

```
rails generate -p migration CreateFoo foo:string
rails generate migration -p CreateFoo foo:string
```

How do I run a "pretend" generate command in Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-p` flag goes at the ***end*** of the command, eg:

```
rails generate migration CreateFoo foo:string -p
```